# Falcon eCommerce accelerator

Tags: ecommerce-tracking

I want to gather information about the Falcon eCommerce accelerator. Can anyone know how it works, how we can see a demo or reference website, and what the differences are between default Magento and this solution?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "Falcom eCommerce accelerator". Could you please add more information?

Comment: On their website, there is a "Success Stories" tab at the top.

Comment: @MarcelH. Falcon eCommerce accelerator is part of the suite of Magento 2 Accelerators , offering a convenient means to swiftly establish your store on this platform through agency support and a range of useful features for rapid setup.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance how we can see the demo